# Robot is printing the same string over and over again

Tags: java, string, clipboard, awtrobot

So I am writing a code where I have a txt file and I have three names in three separate lines in it. After I run the code, I open my MS Word, the app is put in 1 minute delay. Then, the code is supposed to print all the names from my file into MS Word.

But what my code is doing instead, it is just printing the last name in my txt file three times. Now I have printed the names in my IDE with System.out.println() and all of the names are being printed. The problem is when the robot is typing the names in MS Word. Can anyone resolve the issue please?

```
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(br);
        String scan = sc.nextLine();
        TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1);
        while (scan != null) {
            System.out.println("I am here");
            System.out.println(scan);
            scan = "@" + scan;
            StringSelection sl = new StringSelection(scan);
            Clipboard cb = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
            cb.setContents(sl, sl);

            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);


            if (sc.hasNext()) {
                scan = sc.nextLine();
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
```

So my txt file is like this

```
  Ned Stark
  Arya Stark
  Robb Stark
```

and intead of typing all these names, the followig is being typed

```
   @Robb Stark
   @Robb Stark
   @Robb Stark
```

Comment: Your code throws an exception: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot open system clipboard`

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala it doesn’t on my system...

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala it does not on my system either. Have you opened your MS Word before running the code?

Comment: Thenoob I wonder if you’ve tried ‘Clipboard.getData()’ or something of that sort to see if it’s the clipboard or the robot that’s the problem.

Comment: @JavaScriptCoder I have not. I am trying it right now and I'll let you know when I am done. Thanks :)

Comment: @JavaScriptCoder The clipboard is working fine. I have checked, the strings are being copied properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding another 1 second delay inside the `while` loop will solve your problem.

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
```

---

Here's the code. I've done some modifications.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("D:\\f.txt"));
Clipboard cb = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
Robot robot = new Robot();

TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2); // Increase the initial sleep time if necessary.

while (sc.hasNextLine()) { // use hasNextLine() so you can get rid of the if block at the end of the code

    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1); // added another 1 second sleep
    String scan = sc.nextLine();
    scan = "@" + scan;
    System.out.println(scan);
    StringSelection sl = new StringSelection(scan);

    cb.setContents(sl, sl);

    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
}
```

[image]

Comment: @Roshaba Pitigala yes it is working fine now. thanks! also one more thing. The robot is supposed to give a space after the enter while typing, but it is just givng the space. any idea why?

Comment: @TheNoob There's a scape before `@Arya Stark` and `@Robb Stark` if that's what you are asking. You can't see it clearly in the screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

You probably aren't waiting long enough for the paste to complete. You paste really quickly three times. If it takes a while to begin pasting, it might start pasting **after** you put the last thing in the clipboard.

If that's the case, an easy solution is to fill the clipboard with all the lines and then to paste that (this assumes that the `Scanner` input isn't huge, filling up all your memory).

You can use code like this (remember to `import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection`):

```java
TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1);

final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(br);
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    sb.append('@');
    sb.append(scanner.getLine());
    sb.append('\n');
    sb.append(' ');
}

final StringSelection text = new StringSelection(sb.toString());
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(text, text);

final Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

---

A few minor comments on your code, ignoring the potential solution above:

- If you don't change anything else, your loop condition should probably just be `true`, since `nextLine()` never returns `null` (it uses exceptions instead), so how will `scan` ever be `null`?
- You should use `hasNextLine()` instead of `hasNext()` (there's a `hasNext…()` method for every `next…()` method, and you should match them up). `hasNext()` checks for the presence of the next token, not the presence of the next line.

Comment: T Rex, I am actually wanting to copy the names seperately. what I mean is, the Scanner will scan each name individually and the robot will also type it individually. The solution has been given in the next comment. Thanks anyway :D